# Error while trying to create a detail page

Tags: python, django

I've got two classes in my model, like thus:

```
from django.db import models

class nonprofit(models.Model):
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    ........

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organization

class executive(models.Model):
    nonprofit = models.ForeignKey(nonprofit)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    salary = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

My view looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from nonprofit.models import executive

def index(request):
    executives = executive.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('nonprofit/index.html', {'executives': executives})

def detail(request, id):
    e = get_object_or_404(executive, d=id)
    return render_to_response('nonprofit/detail.html', {'executives': e})
```

I keep getting a FieldError:
Cannot resolve keyword 'd' into field. Choices are: id, name, nonprofit, salary, title

I'm a giant noob and can't quite figure out how to fix this. I don't know why it can't resolve it into a field when d equals a field....

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

```
e = get_object_or_404(executive, d=id)
```

should be:

```
e = get_object_or_404(executive, id=id)
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it really should have been 'executive' not 'executives'. As a noob, little typos are just KILLING me right now.